# Should the locale en_US be used if targeting a global market?

Tags: seo, schema.org, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol, localization

When authoring site meta data, if targeting an international market of English-speakers, is it better to use the common `en_US`, or simply `en`, or is there some locale code for specifying that the region is global?

Additionally, when I use the broad term "better", in the case that *"more accurate of description"* and *"more effective for SEO"* are not necessarily the same thing, please elaborate on the differences.

Comment: `en_US` specifically means English as spoken in the US. If you do not need to specify a given country, don't include it in the locale.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek OK. Is it always valid to specify simply `en`? Or is there a global region code I should use?

Comment: `en` is a valid language tag (as is `en_US` of course), only the first part is mandaty (`en`) the rest, like a country, is optional. No need of a global region code.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you, that's exactly the info I was after. Feel free to put it in the form of an answer if you like.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I explicitly used a comment because I didn't want to answer the "SEO" part in the second paragraph as I have nothing useful to say there. I don't know how to address the "better" part, I just added a technical point that `en` is valid and means "all around the world/no specific country".

Comment: @Mentalist What is the context in which you are using this locale?  Is this in the HTML tag's lang attribute or in a hreflang, or somewhere else?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I think it is fine to answer parts of the question in an answer. Though, maybe it is a sign that the question is too broad if it is asking multiple things.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you. Context: my question came up while I was creating Open Graph meta tags, however I believe I will use this for Schema too, and anywhere where specifying language/locale is a good idea.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I agree that answering a question in part is usually OK, as long as it addresses a substantial part of the question. But there have been times when I received an answer that provided enough info to gain 2 upvotes (qualifying as "answered"), while partially unanswered - in which case I have to decide between asking a new (partially duplicate) question or waiting for luck w/ the unsatisfying "answered" one. SE isn't a perfect system. We just try to do our best within the constraints. But this is starting to veer into a topic for Meta, so I'll leave it at that. :-)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Re. the SEO part of my question, I don't believe it is such an issue now. I was probably over-thinking the problem initially. Considering there is no "global" region, and considering your first comment "If you do not need to specify a given country..." that satisfies my question. Conclusion: If the site content is authored by En-speakers in the US then `en_US`, else if authored by En-speakers from various countries or En-speakers in a country where En is not widely used, `en` will suffice.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm taking a look at some major international English sites to get a sense of the way others are approaching this, and it's sort of all over the place... but here's a good example: [Asahi Shimbun](https://www.asahi.com/ajw/) currently uses both `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />` and `<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />` Here `en_US` makes sense because Japan uses mostly US English (not British English). Many sites aren't doing any language specification beyond `<html lang="en">` More examples: The Korea Herald, Bangkok Post, The Moscow Times